# Find the String and the Line number in the Text - python

Tags: python, string

I would like to search for a string in a large text and retrieve its line number.
Is there a method that doesn't include 2 for loops in python.

Comment: take a look at the python tutorial, and maybe take a look at enumerate().

Answer (score 6):

```
for i, line in enumerate(filehandle, 1):
    if text in line:
        print i, line
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` to filter it out. Provide a lambda-function which would be true for the condition you want (eg. here it is match of the line).

And as the second parameter, give a list (iterator) of all the lines you want to check. 
Please note that I use `izip`, to have an iterator of the `(line, line-number)` tuple to the lambda function.

Please find the function below:
As you can see, the limitation here is that this will work only for a file with less than `2^31 - 1` lines.

Also, note that, it returns a list of the line-numbers, of all the matching lines.

```
from itertools import izip
def find_line_num_in_file(file, line):
    f = open(file, "r")
    matches = filter(lambda x: line in x[0], izip(f.readlines(), xrange(-1 + 2**31)))
    f.close()
    return [m[1] for m in matches]
```

If you happen to have the lines already in possession (i.e., not an iterator), you could do this.

```
def find_line_num_in_lines(lines, line):
    matches = filter(lambda x: line in x[0], zip(lines, range(len(lines))))
    return [m[1] for m in matches]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should give you the index

```
In [112]: lines = filehandle.readlines()

In [113]: for elem in lines:
   .....:     if elem.find(substr) > -1:
   .....:         print lines.index(elem)
   .....:
```

including all the index's of multiple occurances of substr

```
In [122]: text = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

In [123]: for elem in text:
   .....:     if elem.find('e') > -1:
   .....:         print text.index(elem)
   .....:
1
```

Comment: @eumiro: yes but it is the element which contains the substr, and index of element containing the substr is required

Comment: @eumiro: i am doing it under an `if` condition which checks if substr is present in the element

Comment: This won't work because the second `readlines()` would return `[]`. After the first `readlines()`, current position would move to the end of the file.

Answer (score -3):

```
try:
    lstLines = fileHandle.readlines():
    lineNumber = lstLines.index("strSearch")
except:
    print "not found"
```

Comment: Even if we provide a `fileHandle` and replace `"strSearch"` with a variable or something this code still wouldn't work. What are we `catch`ing here? No exception is thrown. Also, even if it worked, it would only match whole lines not substrings in them. -1